# Reading docx file in gatsby?

Tags: javascript, gatsby, filereader, docx

I'm trying to read in and then manipulate a docx file with Javascript on a Gatsby site.

Here's what I have so far:

```
const fileInput = require("../static/Hello.docx")
var reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = function () {
  console.log(reader.result)
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Unexpected character '♥' (1:2)

File: static\Hello.docx:1:2
```

What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

docx is plain XML, but as I know its compressed.

1. Unzip the docx file
2. Parse XML
3. Process XML

You can also look for docx parsers. Feed a search engine with "npm docx parser" or similar.